# Print from cloud to office printer

Tags: printing, network-printers

I'm surprised there isn't already an answer for this. Maybe it's so obvious no one needs to ask.

This is the issue. I have a web server running on Ubuntu 16.04 on AWS, it takes orders. When an order comes in it has to be printed on a printer located in an office. The printer is a modern enterprise HP printer. So all features are available.

I can set up the printer drivers on a local Ubuntu machine (desktop but tested via ssh command line), then

```
sudo hp-setup -i
```

can find the local network printer and configure the drivers. So I can then do

```
lp some_file.pdf
```

and it works!!! But...

The remote server on AWS obviously can't find the printer in the office. So plain

```
sudo hp-setup -i
```

doesn't work. I've opened up port 9100 on our WAN interface (Draytek), and allowed it to receive connections only from the remote AWS server. But when I try

```
sudo hp-setup -i my_ip_address
```

or

```
sudo hp-setup -i --port=9100 my_ip_address
```

It returns a stack of errors which scroll off the screen. Starting with

```
HP Linux Imaging and Printing System (ver. 3.16.3)
Printer/Fax Setup Utility ver. 9.0

Copyright (c) 2001-15 HP Development Company, LP
This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
This is free software, and you are welcome to distribute it
under certain conditions. See COPYING file for more details.

(Note: Defaults for each question are maked with a '*'. Press <enter> to accept the default.)

MIB search path: /home/ubuntu/.snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/iana:/usr/share/snmp/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/site:/usr/share/snmp/mibs:/usr/share/mibs/iana:/usr/share/mibs/ietf:/usr/share/mibs/netsnmp
Cannot find module (SNMPv2-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IF-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (IP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (TCP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (UDP-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
Cannot find module (HOST-RESOURCES-MIB): At line 0 in (none)
and so on.....
```

I'm pretty sure this is a common issue, but I can't find a similar question with the answer.

Please don't say 'use HP Eprint' or 'Use Google Cloud Print'. We're already using HP Eprint and it's very very unreliable, which is why I'm researching alternatives. Google Cloud Print is not easy to configure to print from a command line or from within a web app.

I need to know how to configure things so the remote AWS server can talk to the office printer.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a programming question. This would likely be a better fit on Super User or the Ubuntu site. That may be why you couldn't find answers here.

Comment: Ok, I'll try there.